# pass result of one template as param to another template in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

i wanted to apply transformation on output of one template in xslt is there is any way i can pass output of one xslt template as param to another template

main template

```
<xsl:template name="maintemplate">
  <xsl:with-param name="Outputsecondtemplate" select=$sencondtemplate/>
  <xsl:value-of select="translate($Outputsecondtemplate,' -:','')" />
</xsl:template>
```

feeder template

```
<xsl:template name="sencondtemplate">
  <xsl:param name="context"/>
  <xsl:param name="attrib"/>
  <xsl:param name="case"/>
  <xsl:value-of select='$context/value[@attribute=$attrib and @case=$case]' />
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> is there is any way i can pass output of one xslt template as param to another template

You can do:

```
<xsl:call-template name="maintemplate">
    <xsl:with-param name="Outputsecondtemplate">
        <xsl:call-template name="secondtemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="context" select="some-context"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="attrib" select="some-attrib"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="case" select="some-case"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:with-param>
</xsl:call-template>
```

though it is not clear from what context you're doing this.

---

You can also call the sub-template from the main template, e.g.:

```
<xsl:template name="maintemplate">
    <!-- ... -->
    <xsl:variable name="Outputsecondtemplate">
        <xsl:call-template name="secondtemplate">
            <xsl:with-param name="context" select="some-context"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="attrib" select="some-attrib"/>
            <xsl:with-param name="case" select="some-case"/>
        </xsl:call-template>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:value-of select="translate($Outputsecondtemplate,' -:','')" />
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: the second template answered my query